# Navigate XML with mutiple nodes of the same tag name

Tags: xml, vba

I have a simple XML file I cannot change. It contains no attributes, just tags and values. All the  nodes have the same structure:

```xml
<root>
    <Item>
        Data 1 (some data nodes at variable depth)
    </Item>
    <Item>
        Data 2
    </Item>
    ....
    <Item>
        Data N
    </Item>
</root>
```

When I try to access it I get the the values in Data 1.

How do I address the other nodes?

Code snippet;

```vb
Set rst2 = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)
rst2.MoveFirst
If xmlDoc.Load(path) Then
    Set oNodeList = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Item")
    For i = 0 To oNodeList.Length - 1
        Set oNode = oNodeList.Item(i)       ' can I index the list like this ?
        rst2.Edit                           ' a DAO record set (it works OK)
        rst1.MoveFirst
        Do While Not rst1.EOF
            xp = rst1("XPath")              ' the path under oNode
            Set oNode1 = oNodeList(1).selectSingleNode(xp)
            sVal = oNode1.Text              'Here I always get the data from Data 1
            If Len(sVal) > 0 Then
                rst2(rst1("FieldName")) = sVal
            End If
            rst1.MoveNext
        Loop
        rst2.Update
        rst2.MoveNext
    Next i
Else
    MsgBox "Unable to load XML file."
End If
```

How do I set XPath ensuring that I address the sibling nodes?

I tried `Set oNode1=oNodeList(i)` and `Set onode1= oNode(i)` and many other things.

It seems when I use Xpath it overrides the selection of the sibling nodes.

Comment: `Set oNode1 = oNodeList(1).selectSingleNode(xp)` this always uses `oNodeList(1)` - did you mean something like `Set oNode1 = oNode.selectSingleNode(xp)` ?

Comment: Use `SelectNodes` instead of `SelectSingleNode`. The difference is that `SelectNodes` returns a list of nodes whereas `SelectSingleNode` will automatically take the first item from the list and return only that one.

Comment: @Toddleson - seems like OP only expects a single match though?

Comment: You're right, I think they wanted `oNodeList(i).selectSingleNode(xp)`, same thing as `oNode.selectSingleNode(xp)`.

Comment: I'm not sure how you know if you're updating the correct record in `rst2` ?

Answer (score 0):

It works! The clue was: *The difference is that SelectNodes returns a list of nodes whereas SelectSingleNode will automatically take the first item from the list and return only that one.* Many thanks!

Here is the final code:

```
Set oNodeList = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Item")
k = oNodeList.Length - 1
For i = 0 To k
    rst2.Edit
    rst1.MoveFirst
    Do While Not rst1.EOF
        xp = rst1("XPath")
        Set oNodeList = xmlDoc.selectNodes(xp)
        Set oNode = oNodeList(i)
        sVal = oNode.Text
        If Len(sVal) > 0 Then
            rst2(rst1("FieldName")) = sVal
        End If
        rst1.MoveNext
    Loop
    rst2.Update
    rst2.MoveNext
Next i
```